# Viewing auto-created printers on a 2008 R2 Remote Desktop Services server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, printing, remote-desktop-services

On our 2003 Terminal Servers I am able to view any auto-created printers for users connected to that server, however on a new 2008 R2 RDS server I can only view local printers and my own auto-created printer(s).

I have local and domain admin privileges.

Is there something I need to change to be able to view all client printers? Is it possible?

I have had a look for permissions relating to this but couldn't really find much that looked relevant.

Comment: I don't have any answer, I'm trying to clarify for others. Are you asking if it's possible to see the printers that originate at the client and get redirected through RDP? That is, those printers that appear as "Bill's Printer (redirected)"?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a machine handy to look at right now but I strongly suspect what you're seeing is an artifact of User Account Control. You might try starting an instance of Explorer without UAC (elevated) and see if it makes a difference. The quick-and-dirty to start an elevated Explorer is as follows:

- Open an elevated "Command Prompt" with "Run as Administrator".
- Open the "Start" menu, depress and hold CTRL and SHIFT and right-click anywhere in the "empty" area of the Start menu. You'll get a context menu with "Properties" and "Exit Explorer". Choose "Exit Explorer".
- Run "Explorer" from the elevated "Command Prompt". This copy of Explorer will be elevated. You can verify by clicking "Start" and "Run". If you see the text "This task will be created with administrative privileges." under the "Open" text-box then you've got an elevated Explorer.

When you're done either logoff or re-open Explorer from a non-elevated "Command Prompt".

Comment: No luck. I didn't have "Exit Explorer" in my context-menu so killed it via task manager, but still couldn't see any other printers even when running elevated.

Comment: Hmm... I'll have to look on a real box when I have some time.

Comment: No worries, I disabled UAC entirely and still can't see it.